# Django ORM generated query is not expected

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

**Question desc**

1. Execute a query by django orm

```
test_result = table1.objects.filter(q_filter).values(*groupby_columns).annotate(**{d: Sum(d) for d in data_columns})
```

2. Got an error

```
Unknown column 'table2.column1' in 'field list'
```

3. It's strange, because I execute query on model `table1` but got an error on model `table2`

**Debug**

1. print the sql

```
print(test_result.query)
```

I got this:

```
SELECT `table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2`, SUM(`table1`.`data`) AS `data` FROM `table2` WHERE (`table1`.`column3` = 4 AND `table1`.`column4` = 0 AND `table1`.`column1` >= 2020-04-01 AND `table1`.`column1` <= 2020-04-08) GROUP BY `table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2` ORDER BY NULL;
```

2. I'm not sure if there is a cache in django orm, and it record the query clause that I execute last time, so cause this error.
3. It often happen, but recover after I restart my service.

**Env**

- Python3.6.9
- Django2.0.2
- Mysql5.6

Does anyone meet this problem. Kindly to talk

**Additional**

table1 & table2 have the same struct and the same orm logic

Comment: I believe one of your column is a FK for another table, isn't it?

Comment: no, table1 & table2 are two independent model. There is only one connection between them: use the same orm logic

Comment: We don't see neither q_filter nor groupby_columns

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly (if you hope to get any useful help that is...).